# How to return __str__(self) in ModelAdmin list_display

Tags: django, django-admin

I have the following model:

```
class Administrator(models.Model):
    // code

    def __str__(self):
        title = 'Administrator ' + str(self.pk)
        return title
```

This returns titles for the objects as `Administrator 1`, `Administrator 2`, etc.

How do I return the `title` in `list_display` for a `ModelAdmin`?:

```
class AdministratorAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = Administrator
    list_display = ('pk', 'id', 'title???')
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
class AdministratorAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = Administrator
    list_display = ('pk', 'id', '__str__')
```

Comment: Only downside to using `__str__` is that you can't sort on this field in the Django admin. For that you'd need a custom function for the list_display, I think